# Win32 WriteFile return 0 bytes as the number of byte written. lpBuffer contained 4455 bytes

Tags: c, windows, debugging, winapi

I have the following code which creates two files. When the write operation for the last 4455 byte is invoked it returns 0 as the number of bytes written. Could this be due to the dwFlagAttributes of sequential scan and no buffering?

```
hIn = CreateFile (fIn, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | SSF | NBF, NULL);

Desired Access: Generic Read
Disposition:    Open
Options:    Sequential Access, No Buffering, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File
Attributes: N
ShareMode:  None
AllocationSize: n/a
OpenResult: Opened

hOut = CreateFile (fOut, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS,
                    FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL | SSF | NBF, NULL);

Desired Access: Generic Write, Read Attributes
Disposition:    OverwriteIf
Options:    Sequential Access, No Buffering, Synchronous IO Non-Alert, Non-Directory File
Attributes: N
ShareMode:  None
AllocationSize: 0
OpenResult: Created
```

After the files are created there is a while loop that reads file1. Then writes the bytes to file2. file1 is approximately 13MB.

```
while (ReadFile (hIn, aBuffer, BUF_SIZE, &nIn, NULL) && nIn > 0 && WriteOK) {
        for (iCopy = 0; iCopy < nIn; iCopy++)
            ccBuffer [iCopy] = (BYTE)((aBuffer [iCopy] + shift) % 256);
        WriteOK = WriteFile (hOut, ccBuffer, nIn, &nOut, NULL);
    }
```

From the disassembly below its evident that the last 4455 bytes are not being written to file2. Could this be due to the CreateFile dwFlagAttributes?

```
0:000> kb
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child
00 0018bd00 00411612 00000038 0018bdf8 00001167 kernel32!WriteFile
01 0018fe64 0041144c 00273a99 00273ac9 0000000a cci!cci_f+0x162
02 0018ff44 00411bbb 00000004 00273a78 002723e8 cci!main+0x6c
03 0018ff88 7698336a 7efde000 0018ffd4 77c29f72 cci!__tmainCRTStartup+0x122
04 0018ff94 77c29f72 7efde000 76d02536 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
05 0018ffd4 77c29f45 00411122 7efde000 00000000 ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
06 0018ffec 00000000 00411122 7efde000 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b

0:000> dd 0018bd00 la
0018bd00  0018fe64 00411612 00000038 0018bdf8
0018bd10  00001167 0018fe34 00000000 0018ff44
0018bd20  0018fe78 00000000

0:000> $number of bytes to be written 0x1167
0:000> .formats 00001167
Evaluate expression:
  Hex:     00001167
  Decimal: 4455
  Octal:   00000010547
  Binary:  00000000 00000000 00010001 01100111
  Chars:   ...g
  Time:    Wed Dec 31 20:14:15 1969
  Float:   low 6.24278e-042 high 0
  Double:  2.20106e-320

0:000> gu
eax=00000000 ebx=00000000 ecx=76b2df07 edx=00000057 esi=0018bd1c edi=0018fe64
eip=00411612 esp=0018bd1c ebp=0018fe64 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=0023  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000246
cci!cci_f+0x162:
00411612 cmp     esi,esp

0:000> $number of bytes written
0:000> dd 0018fe34 l1
0018fe34  00000000
```

[image]

Comment: If `WriteFile` fails, call `GetLastError` to find out why.

Comment: @JonathanPotter I get an invalid parameter was passed to the parameter or function. That's not clear to me because the operation succeeded previously in the loop. The only argument to write file that change is the size of the numberofbytes and the in buffer

Comment: I created a file 80kb (81920) and as stated by David with proper alignment the write operation succceeds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are writing non-buffered, you need to adhere to the alignment requirements that are documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc644950.aspx

Specifically the file access must start at a multiple of the volume sector size, and have a size that is a multiple of the volume sector size. Your `4455` sized buffer does not meet the second requirement.

Of course, if you want to write those final `4455` bytes and no more then you are in a quandry. You need to round it up to a multiple of the volume sector size and write the actual `4455` bytes followed by padding. The set the file pointer back to the end of those `4455` bytes, and call `SetEndOfFile`.

Comment: You might want to say something about the obvious follow on question (the file should not contain the padding bytes), possibly by mentioning the `SetEndOfFile` function.

Comment: the last 4455 bytes are remaining bytes in the source file. So If I understand correct I will have to round the 4455 to a multiple of the volume vector size. Interesting feedback